# Importing user-created Python modules and data files from relative directories

Tags: python, directory, pycharm, python-import

I'm building a set of Python modules that depend on each other.

My file directory currently looks like:

```
.
├── utilities
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── utility.py
│   ├── data.csv
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   |── functions
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── function.py
└── __init__.py
```

Further, `function.py` imports data from `utilities/data.csv`.

From the top-level directory (`.`), I run `python3 src/functions/function.py`.

And I receive the following import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/functions/function.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utilities.utility import UtilityFunctionA
ImportError: No module named 'utilities'
```

How do I properly import `utilities` from the `function.py` file? Or should I not be running nested files in the first place, and instead running files at the top-level of the directory?

The imports are successful when running this code from within PyCharm.

Silly question, but I've been unable to figure it out despite reading a lot of documentation (and Googling).

---

UPDATE:

Using `python3 -m src.functions.function` works to run the module from the command line with proper imports and with successfully loading the csv.

However, when I then run the module from within PyCharm, for instance using

[image]

Now I receive the error that `OSError: File b'utilities/data.csv' does not exist`

Is there any way to setup my module to run both from within PyCharm and also from the command line?

Comment: Guido seems to think that running scripts from within a module's directory is an anti-pattern (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006793.html), so while you can hack this to work, it will never be easy/pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to do - `from utilities.utility import UtilityFunctionA` - from within `function.py` , when running from the top level directory - `.` . You need to run the python file as a module , using `-m` option. Example -

```
python3 -m src.functions.function
```

---

But The above method only works if you always run from the `.` directory (top-level directory) . I always either add the top-level directory manually into the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Or use `os.path` and relative path to add it to `sys.path` programmatically using `__file__`. Example -

```
import sys
import os.path
path_to_top = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..','..'))
sys.path.append(path_to_top)
```

After this do the import. If the directory structures would always remain the same, this would work even in other systems, without having to set any environment variable.

---

As per the updated requirements -

> Now I receive the error that OSError: File b'utilities/data.csv' does not exist
>
> Is there any way to setup my module to run both from within PyCharm and also from the command line?

For reading files, Python uses the current working directory as the start point , and all relative paths are resolved relative to the current working directory. It is never a good idea to rely on the current working directory to be a particular directory as we can run python scripts from anywhere using absolute path to the script. For loading files as well, we can use `os.path` and relative paths to create the absolute path to the file. Example -

```
import os.path
path_to_datacsv = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..','..','utilities,'data.csv'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Anand -- I updated the question to reflect a further problem I discovered after attempting your answer. Sorry to change the question from under your feet!

Comment: Updated the answer. Also please note you can still just directory change the working directory in your pycharm to be the top level directory and it should work for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "directory change the working directory in your pycharm"?

Comment: Check if this helps - https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/switching-between-working-directories.html

Comment: I may be really dense today, but that link seems to only apply to Mercurial VCS.

Comment: Oh sorry, you can try checking here - https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configuration-python.html . I don't use Pycharm , so all I can help you is knowledge from these docs :) . But again, I would suggest you use the method I said in the answer, but that would require changing code.

Comment: Perfect! In PyCharm, going to `Run -> Edit Configurations -> Working directory:` made the script functional in both places. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This imports properly:

```
python3 -m src.functions.function
```

Based on [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python#comment18422072_73149)